# Bing Api geocoding search using directions

Tags: geocoding, bing-maps

I have some data like this:

[image]

Can I create an accurate query using the bing map api using this data?  if so, what is the syntax?  I tried this for the 1st row:

q=0.013%20miles%20E%20Webser%20st%20and%20Holtz%20ln%20Cary,%20NC

and did not get the correct results.  If Bing cannot do this, are there any services that can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this wouldn't be supported by the routing service in Bing Maps and you will be hard pressed to find any automated system that is able to handle this. This will likely be a manual process.